# How to make text be transparent and let the backround be seen only trough letters?

Tags: css

How do I make element visible only inside letters and not around them?
I want to position absolutely an element over some text and only make the element visible inside letters.

Is there something like "overflow: hidden" for the text?

[Text to set overflow : hidden on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48iGQ.png)

@Edit: Maybe I did not express myself well enough, I want to put some div or image etc. over some text and make it so the div/image, only shows trough letters as if they were holes cut in the foreground element, but I also want to keep text color when there is nothing "covering" it;

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want but there is the text-flow, that can help you.: [text-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Look at this code, can help as well :

```
   width: 200px;  //define a fixed width 
    white-space: nowrap; //it's like flex-wrap: nowrap, avoid the line breaks
    overflow: auto; //or hidden in your case
```

Comment: You didn't get me, I want some text to act like a hole in the container so I could see the background of text's div. In the image I've attached you can see a diagonal white line over the text, I want it look like a "shine" effect, I've done animation but I can't get the white line to be visible only on letters.

Comment: Is something like that: [video-css](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EWaReUnFV20) or [video-css2](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Tgd7B4C-YUk) ?